# Codeigniter validation is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am new in codeigniter .I have done validation for my project .But it is not working fine .I have written my all code here .First is view page and second is my controller page.Please help anyone

```
<?php $this->load->helper('form');  
  echo validation_errors();  
  echo form_open('SM_in_controller/sm_login_action');
?>

  <input class="login_input" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="login_button" id="login_button"/>
</form>
```

and my controller

```
public function sm_login_action() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please add some information about your error message / error logs to let us help you.

Comment: You need use `$this->form_validation->run()` to call to test.

Comment: hi 110precent , i added this $this->form_validation->run() . it is working fine .But i have set validation rules for fields na ...it is not working .Directly it is redirect to form action ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, when you call the "run" method is when the proccess is done:

```
public function sm_login_action() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');

   if( $this->form_validation->run() ) { // Return TRUE on success
        // Success
   } else {
      // Failure
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to check only this function $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required'); else everything is working ...

Comment: If you do not call "run" method, does will not work as expected. After call "$this->form_validation->run();" should be work. try.

Comment: i tried ... before executing  $this->form_validation->run() i have written code for validation right ? so first validation should work ..right ?

Comment: How I said, look at this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules

Comment: thanks wrivas !! actually i did one mistake !! i was not redirecting to that page in which i written validation_error() .you are right .

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[users.email]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }

    public function username_check($str)
    {
        if ($str == 'test')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

try this for more details. 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: thnaks for giving help ...these thing i tried ...same code only i implemented .

Comment: no error is showing .it is redirecting to page which i written in my controller .See my controller here ...public function sm_login_action() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');

   if( $this->form_validation->run() ) { // Return TRUE on success
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
   } else {
       $this->load->view('formerror');
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input class="login_input" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" required/>
```

Hope this helps